# Bind constructor arguments to Xamarin.Forms' GoogleMaps

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.forms, mvvmcross

I develop simple Xamarin.Forms application with GoogleMaps using MVVMCross. My goal is to center maps' position to user's current location while launching it. Unfortunately I don't know how to bind these values to GoogleMaps' constructor. Right now it's just static value but I want to pass values of latitude and longitude from CurrentLocation object (which has these properties).

View:

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <maps:Map MapType="Street" IsShowingUser="True" HasZoomEnabled="True">
        <x:Arguments>
            <maps:MapSpan>
                <x:Arguments>
                    <maps:Position>
                        <x:Arguments>
                            <x:Double>56.368533</x:Double>
                            <x:Double>3.258646</x:Double>
                        </x:Arguments>
                    </maps:Position>
                    <x:Double>0.01</x:Double>
                    <x:Double>0.01</x:Double>
                </x:Arguments>
            </maps:MapSpan>
        </x:Arguments>
    </maps:Map>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

Here's part of my ViewModel:

```
public class NearbyBollardsMapViewModel : MvxViewModel
{
    private Location _currentLocation;

    public Location CurrentLocation
    {
        get => _currentLocation;
        set
        {
            _currentLocation = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => CurrentLocation);
        }
    }

    public NearbyBollardsMapViewModel(ILocationService locationService)
    {
        this._locationService = locationService;
        CurrentLocation = _locationService.GetCurrentUsersLocation().Result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a PCL class that extends from Maps and add a BindableProperty to it.

### 1º - Create a class and extend it from Xamarin.Forms.Maps.Map

(I included the code for the Bindable Property, you can read more [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/bindable-properties))

```
public class BindableMap : Xamarin.Forms.Maps.Map
{
    public BindableMap()
    {

    }

    public MapSpan MapSpan
    {
        get { return (MapSpan)GetValue(MapSpanProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MapSpanProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty MapSpanProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
                                                     propertyName: "MapSpan",
                                                     returnType: typeof(MapSpan),
                                                     declaringType: typeof(BindableMap),
                                                     defaultValue: null,
                                                     defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.TwoWay,
                                                     validateValue: null,
                                                     propertyChanged: MapSpanPropertyChanged);

    private static void MapSpanPropertyChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
    {
        try
        {
            var thisInstance = bindable as BindableMap;
            var newMapSpan = newValue as MapSpan;

            thisInstance?.MoveToRegion(newMapSpan);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
    
}
```

### 2º - Add the property that will be used for binding the MapSpan in the ViewModel

```
private MapSpan _mapSpanView;
public MapSpan MapSpanView
{
    get { return _mapSpanView; }
    set { SetProperty(ref _mapSpanView, value); }
}

...

Position position = new Position((double)Latitude, (double)Longitude);
MapSpanView = MapSpan.FromCenterAndRadius(
                            prospectPosition,
                            Distance.FromMeters(2500)
                        );
```

### 3º - And then Bind it in the xaml

```
xmlns:map="clr-namespace:YourNameSpace.Mobile.TheFolderWhereTheClassIs"

...

<StackLayout x:Name="mapHolder">
    <map:BindableMap
                    x:Name="map"
                    MapSpan="{Binding MapSpanView}"
                    MapType="Street" IsShowingUser="True" HasZoomEnabled="True"/>
</StackLayout>
```

Comment: What is BindableProspectDetailMap? What in it?

Comment: EDIT: it is BindableMap

Comment: @Winteriscoming you are correct, it is indeed BindableMap instead of BindableProspectDetailMap, that name is what i used in one of my projects, and then in this anwser i changed to BindableMap and forgot to change it on the usage. Thank you for noticing, i fixed the typo in the anwser